# too many redirects error after publishing on cPanel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, cpanel, laravel-5.3

Why do I have too many redirections error?
It's not always... just sometimes when I tried to acess the site.

I don't know if it is related to the fact that my website is hosted on a shared hosting with cPanel, but I never seen this error before.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   App::setLocale('pt');
   return view('index');
});
Route::get('/works', function () {
    App::setLocale('pt');
    return view('works');
});
Route::get('/orders', function () {
    App::setLocale('pt');
    return view('orders');
});
Route::get('/contact', function () {
    App::setLocale('pt');
    return view('contact');
});
Route::get('/budget', function () {
    App::setLocale('pt');
    return view('budget');
});


Route::get('/{locale}', function ($locale = 'pt') {
    valid($locale);
    return view('index');
});
Route::get('/{locale}/works', function ($locale = 'pt') {
    valid($locale);
    return view('works');
});
Route::get('/{locale}/orders', function ($locale = 'pt') {
    valid($locale);
    return view('orders');
});
Route::get('/{locale}/contact', function ($locale = 'pt') {
    valid($locale);
    return view('contact');
});
Route::get('/{locale}/budget', function ($locale = 'pt') {
    valid($locale);
    return view('budget');
});

Route::post('/orders', 'FormsController@orders');
Route::post('/budget', 'FormsController@budget');


function valid($locale) {
    if($locale != 'pt' && $locale != 'fr' && $locale != 'en' && strlen($locale) > 2)
        App::setLocale('pt');
    else
        App::setLocale($locale);
}
```

To reacess to website, I need to clean my cookies... Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

instead of check locale in every routes, use route group, it's very easier. also you could use AppServiceProvider class to validate locale.

Comment: but it is the cause of my roblem?